# Quick Divergence Question

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So I was given the following prompt:

"Determine whether the series converges absolutely or conditionally, or diverges."

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}*n^2}{(n+1)^{2}}\right)$

I guess I'm a bit confused about what the $nth$ term test would look like here. I understand that it needs to be used in this context but I'm a bit confused about what the specific application would look like. Would it just be as simple as taking the limit of the function as it approaches infinity? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That’s right. $$ (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} =(-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{(1+1/n)^2} \to (-1)^{n+1}$$ The terms bounce between $1$ and $-1$, so the limit doesn’t exist. But this means that the series diverges, as a series converges only if the terms $\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

To see whether a series $\sum_{n} a_n$ converges absolutely, one needs to check that $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges. In your case, you need to check that \begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big{|}\frac{-1^{n+1}n^2}{{(n+1)}^2}\Big{|}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{{(n+1)}^2}\quad \text{converges}.\end{equation}

However, the above series very clearly does not converge because its summand converges to 1.

Similarly, the original series does not converge, because $\frac{n^2}{{(n+1)}^2}$ converges to 1, so you have $-1^{n+1}$ in the limit, which just oscillates.